# "Half" or "Half of"

Tags: word-usage

> 1.**Half** the world’s marine resources lie in island waters
>     2.**Half of** the world’s marine resources lie in island waters

Which one should I choose?

Comment: Answered here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217600/should-i-use-half-the-time-or-half-of-the-time

Answer (score 2):

Half the world's marine resources ....

Half of the world's marine resources ...

Both are correct.

You can use "half" or "half of" in front of a noun phrase beginning with a determiner.  "Half" is a bit more common than "half of".